# How to solve (permissions) problem of Azure Windows 10 VM not Starting with AutoStart

Tags: azure, automation, permissions, virtual-machine

I have an Azure Windows 10 VM (Standard D2as v4 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)). I have tried using the automated tasks section to start this VM up and shut it down automatically. However, the auto start task repeatedly fails. I do not understand why. Here is the error that I have found:

Unauthorized!

{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
"message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
}
}

I do not understand what is going on at all am afraid. If someone could please explain and help resolve!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I have created **`Virtual machine`** in my environment and added two tasks like **`Azure start VM and Azure stop VM`**

**Task1 - start VM**
Home -> Virtual machine -> Automation -> task

[image]

I have Authenticated connection both **`Azure VM (azurevm)`** and **`Office 365 Outlook (office365)`**

[image]

**Configuration:**

[image]

After created task1 it will appears on the  **Tasks**  list.

[image]

After the selected task runs, you get an email that looks like this example:

[image]

In the tasks list-> task1->In that task's **Runs** column, select **View**.

[image]

**Task2 - Stop VM**

Similar process which I took to reproduce:

**Mail:**

[image]

**View:**

[image]

> { "error": { "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant", "message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer
> 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL)'https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."} }

The above error occurs due to not have enough permission.

- You must have certain permissions to enable VMs for the Start&Stop VMs.
- Kindly check and make sure you have role of **Contributor** to your logic app.
- In permission they has some of the pre-existing Automation account and new Automation account for log analytics workspace  kindly check the below reference link.

[image]

**Logic app:**

logic app -> task1->Run history

[image]

**Reference:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management
- [Azure Logic App: Azure VM Connector - InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/405123/azure-logic-app-azure-vm-connector-invalidauthenti.html)